# programmatic way to check which version is installed?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there a way through javascript to see what version (or rollup) the crm organization/server is on? What I really want to know is if I am on UR11 or before.

I've tried:

1. [Xrm.Page.context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328399.aspx) - but nothing about versions (did I miss something?)
2. Checking if (crmForm == null) (Since that was disabled as of UR12) The problem is that if the org enables HTC support then crmForm will not be null, and I need to know what version with or without HTC support enabled.

What I've done for now is put the onus on the solution installer to modify a javascript file that has the "isRollup12" variable to true or false, which is quite clunky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a global JS variable you could check:

```
alert(APPLICATION_FULL_VERSION);
//on UR12 '5.0.9690.3236'
//on UR11 '5.0.9690.2839'
//and so on...
```

But this method isn't supported, so use at your own risk.

Comment: good to know, but not so much reliable, for example one crm online returns to me 5.0.9690.3351, a version listened neither in this link: [http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8062.crm-2011-build-and-version-numbers-for-update-rollups.aspx](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8062.crm-2011-build-and-version-numbers-for-update-rollups.aspx)

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know that abour the online version.You could then use something like that: `if(APPLICATION_FULL_VERSION.slice(-4) >= 3236)`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Are these global variables documented? Can you link something? Thank you.

Comment: These global variables are not documented and not supported by Microsoft, this means that the behavior (and the return values/structure) can change in next rollups.

Comment: @BenPatterson1 You can use the RetrieveVersion SOAP message (clunky, but possible, in JavaScript) to get the server's version string in this format without relying on unsupported functionality.

Answer (score 2):

you can check if the getClientUrl function is defined, it's a new function included inside UR12.

```js
var isRollup12 = false;
if (Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl !== undefined) {
   isRollup12 = true;
}
```

Comment: Clever, thanks! I assume we're still SoL when it comes to learning the exact rollup though, eh?